# Why are my application settings not getting persisted?

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

So I have some settings that are of the **user** scope, but for some reason, they are not being saved to the .exe.config file. I do the following:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Email = "new@value.com";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Yet I look at the settings file in the debug folder and it is still the default that I set in visual studio. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

User settings are specific to the user, so they wouldn't get saved back to the .exe.config file, which is system wide.

From the docs of `LocalSettingsProvider`:

> Application-scoped settings and the
>   default user-scoped settings are
>   stored in a file named
>   application.exe.config, which is
>   created in the same directory as the
>   executable file. Application
>   configuration settings are read-only.
>   Specific user data is stored in a file
>   named `username.config`, stored under
>   the user's home directory.

So for a UserSettingsTest application just run from VS under the debugger (hence the vshost bit) I ended up with a path of:

```
C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\UserSettingsTest
  \UserSettingsTest.vshost.e_Url_pdqoppugkz1vaawbhwkkcu5ibxpi2fgu
  \1.0.0.0\user.config
```

Comment: I have WinXP, but I didn't see any such file or folder in C:\Documents and Settings\Ryan\Application Data. Is this the right place?

Comment: XP will be C:\Documents and Settings\Ryan\Local Settings\Application Data

Comment: I have read over 2 dozen answers and articles on this today, and this is the only one to get the name and location of the file correct.  Of course, it's Jon Skeet.

Comment: Great answer, save time.

Answer (score 21):

If you have your Assembly info set to automatically generate any version numbers (1.0.*), then every time you debug your app the version number will be different, and so will be creating a new file every time.

If this is the case you will need to perform an upgrade on the settings file:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()
```

You can also set a setting of `NeedsUpgrading` to `true` by default and set it to false after performing an upgrade so that end users who are not changing version numbers every time the app is started will not be Upgrading all the time

Comment: didn't know that there was a method called upgrade, neat.

Comment: I used this approach here and had success: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/522191-how-maintain-user-config-settings-when-upgrading

Comment: Awesome answer, and elegant NeedsUpgrading tip!

Answer (score 2):

All user scope settings saved under application data with within a folder which indicates the version of your application and the name.

You can see these folders by clicking "synchronize" in your "application settings" dialog.

In Vista generally:

- c:\users[currentuser]\AppData\Local[CompanyName][AppName]\version
- c:\users[currentuser]\AppData\Roaming[CompanyName][AppName]\version

Done this way due to settings are related with **current user** and **UAC**. In Vista also you can see even the application-wide settings are not stored in the config file.

[CompanyName] and [ProductName] comes from your Assembly Information settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when running the Debug version it always rebuilds and auto increments the version. The new version expected the user.config file to be in C:\Users\Adrian\AppData\Local\Company\Project\Version. As this was a new version, the file didn't exist and I got the defaults again. You can check for this by changing a setting, saving, and then manually run the exe again (in the bin\debug\... folder). If this is your problem then it will have remembered your change.

To fix this you can use the `Settings.Default.Upgrade()` Method. The potential problem with this is that if you run it every time it will always replace your most recent settings with old ones.

SOLUTION
Add a new setting using the settings editor:

```
SettingsHaveBeenUpgraded : bool : User : false
```

In Program.cs Main() add:

```
    if (!Settings.Default.SettingsHaveBeenUpgraded)
    {
        Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        Settings.Default.SettingsHaveBeenUpgraded = true;
    }
```

This will ensure the upgrade only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

I use a little config-file to solve this:

```
    private static void ReadSettings()
    {
        if (File.Exists("settings.cfg"))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("settings.cfg"))
            {
                LaatsteSpecifiekeFoutMelding = sr.ReadLine();
                LaatsteAlgemeneFoutMelding = sr.ReadLine();
            }
    }
    private static void SaveSettings()
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("settings.cfg",false))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(LaatsteSpecifiekeFoutMelding);
            sw.WriteLine(LaatsteAlgemeneFoutMelding);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

"User" defined settings are recorded in app.config along with "Application" defined settings. In reality however, "User" named settings is a misnomer and quite misleading. They should be called "Default User" settings.

When a new user accesses the application, they will be assigned the "User" setting by default.

User settings are only saved to the actual User's user.config settings file if they differ from the "Default User" setting located in the app.config file.