# Persist application scope settings

Tags: c#

I have some application level settings for a windows form, which I can read using `Properties.Settings.Default.offset`. I wanted to persist these settings, so that these settings can be used later.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/453230/1175065) post at SO, I tried the following-

```
Properties.Settings.Default["offset"] = this.offsetTextBox.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

But it is not saving the value, since I can see the old value even after changing it.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my application settings not getting persisted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054422/why-are-my-application-settings-not-getting-persisted)

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, inspection of the generated code and the question, "[Why are my application settings not getting persisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054422/why-are-my-application-settings-not-getting-persisted)", application-scoped settings are read-only.

To update application-scoped settings, you'll need to change the appropriate `<appsettings>` value in your `app.config` file:

- [Update app.config system.net setting at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980440/update-app-config-system-net-setting-at-runtime)
- http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-change-appconfig-file-run-time-using-c/

Note that a change to an `app.config` file is supposed to restart the app domain, so trying to update your own `app.config` may behave a little differently than what you might expect.

Also note that the changes will be made to the generated `*.exe.config` file in your `bin` directory, not to the `app.config` file in your Visual Studio solution.

Another thing to consider: in a deployed application, unless you run with "elevated privileges", you're also unlikely to have write access to the `app.config` file.

If you want to persist/update this sort of app settings, take a page from the OS X book and create a `*.plist`:

1. On application start, check for an XML file for your settings in a known location to which that app has read/write access. In OS X, the app-level settings live in `/Library/Preferences`; user level preferences live in `~/Library/Preferences`.

   If it doesn't exist, create it, populating it with the default values for the settings in question (which could be as simple as copying your `<appsettings>` element from `app.config`.
2. Read your app-level settings from that file.
3. Place a `FileSystemWatcher` on that file to hook any changes and update the settings.

There you go. Now, you can update your app-level settings to your heart's content. If you ever need to revert, all you have to do is blow away the `*.plist` file.