# how to modify app.config for visual studio.net 2003, .NET 1.1

Tags: app-config, edit, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

```
Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
config.AppSettings.Settings("test").Value = "blah"
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

not work

I want to edit/modify app.config

I use visual studio.net 2003 and .NET1.1

Answer (score 0):

This question was already asked here: [Why are my application settings not getting persisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054422/why-are-my-application-settings-not-getting-persisted)

Probably you're looking at wrong folder while in debug/release mode.