# How to get the current value of a Property Setting at run-time using a loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, application-settings

I have a Property named `A` and it was set to the value `AAA` via the Properties Setting Window in Visual Studio (Project → Properties → Settings).

I can obtain the original value for the property `A` using this loop.
If I change the value, to say `NewValue`, I can get the new value using the code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.A
```

However, within the loop, I don't know how to get the current property value without using the syntax:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.VariableName
```

for example:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.A= "NewValue";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
foreach (SettingsProperty _currentProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_currentProperty.Name + "," + _currentProperty.DefaultValue.ToString());
}
```

The above loop shows the original value of the property (old default value which was `AAA`).

I have checked the `user.config` file and made sure it is showing `NewValue`.

I assume that there must be some way to refer to the current value using a property or a method I don't know (maybe I should iterate another collection?).

The question is, how to display this new value inside the `foreach` loop above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054422/why-are-my-application-settings-not-getting-persisted Would this solve your problem? Check `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()`

Comment: Or in other word, You set value but read default value.

Comment: @LouisGo, thanks for the hint, the link discusses a different issue. In my case, I am using "user scoped settings" only. Upgrade method is useful when the version changes, which is not my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current `Properties.Settings` values are returned in a [SettingsPropertyValueCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingspropertyvaluecollection) Class when querying a [SettingsProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingsprovider) (if no Provider is defined for a setting, the default Provider, [LocalFileSettingsProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.localfilesettingsprovider), is used).

The current code is modifying the value of a Setting and then inspect these values after the settings have been saved to the local storage.
The code iterates the `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties` collection, corresponding to the [ApplicationSettingsBase.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.properties) property, a [SettingsPropertyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingspropertycollection) collection, which contains [SettingsProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingsproperty) objects, used internally to represent the metadata of configuration properties.

This class can only return the Default value of the associated Setting.

To inspect the current values associated to Properties Settings, the code should instead iterate the aforementioned `SettingsPropertyValueCollection`, returned by  [ApplicationSettingsBase.PropertyValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.propertyvalues) property, which enumerates the  `SettingsPropertyValue` objects.
The [PropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingspropertyvalue.propertyvalue) property of these objects returns the run-time value currently assigned to the Setting.

To return the current values, the code can then be modified in:

```
foreach (SettingsPropertyValue prop in Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} -> {prop.PropertyValue}");
}
```

---

A couple of notes about the Application Settings:

[Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/application-settings-overview) are organized in 2 main categories:

1. Application Settings (Settings in the **`Application`** scope)
   Read-only, no local storage is associated, so cannot be changed at run-time.
   These settings are stored int the **`app.config`** files, which is the copied to the **`[Application].exe.config`** file when a Project is built.
2. User Settings (Settings in the **`User`** scope) (applies to Visual Studio 2017+)
   These settings are stored along with the Application settings, but have associated local storage files, used to store values that a User (or the Application) can change at run-time:
   2.1 A **`user.config`** file stored in the current User profile in the

   ```
   [User]/AppData/Local/[CompanyName]/[ProductName].exe_<hash>/[Assembly Version]
   ```

   section, if the setting's `Roaming` attribute is set to `false`.
   2.2 A **`user.config`** file stored in the current User profile in the

   ```
   [User]/AppData/Roaming/[CompanyName]/[ProductName]/[File Version]
   ```

   section, if the setting `Roaming` attribute is set to `true` instead.

The original values of settings in the `User` scope, the `Default` values, are not modified when a new value is assigned to the Setting.

---

- Settings in the User scope can save new values assigned at run-time, using the [ApplicationSettingsBase.Save()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.save) method:

  ```
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
  ```
- An application can reload the last saved values (to discard recent changes, maybe), with the [ApplicationSettingsBase.Reload()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload) method:

  ```
  Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
  ```
- To discard all changes made to the User settings, the Settings can be reset to default values using the [ApplicationSettingsBase.Reset()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reset) method:

  ```
  Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanations. Excellent reference indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was provided as a link in a comment to my question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/69223410/2287576) and part of it helped.