# Where are settings saved wiithin the context of BricsCAD?

Tags: c#, .net, settings, bricscad, zwcad

My C# DLL project has [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and the defaut values are held automatically in the `xxx.dll.cong` file.

When I perform a save of the settings:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

They are correctly read back in when I display my form. But I can't work out where the **users** saved version of the config file is kept? I tried to look in `%localappdata%` and nothing is there.

To summarise:

1. This is a .Net DLL tool bring run inside BricsCAD.
2. We are using the `Properties.Settings` concept.
3. Where is the users `Save()` version of the file kept?

---

#### Update

This is the closest [conversation](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/how-to-use-config-files-with-autocad-net-dlls/td-p/6229673) I could find about this subject (related to AutoCAD). It is still relevant because my tool is used by three CAD packages:

- AutoCAD
- BricsCAD
- ZWCAD

But the linked discussion does not actually answer my question. Clearly the "settings" are persisting. But they are not persisting in the `%localappdat%` folder for my tool. I have now tested with both BricsCAD and ZWCAD and still can't find them.

---

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-setting-between-application-sessions?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) the configuration file should be updated. But the config file where the DLL is is not updating. Even though the mechanism works. The persisted settings are somewhere else.

Comment: What about `%appdata%`? If nothing helps, try using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: @Steeeve I can't see anything in the `%appdata%` folder.

Comment: @Steeeve can’t work out Process Monitor.

Comment: @Steeeve See my answer ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the MS-DOS command [`findstr`](https://www.computerhope.com/findstr.htm) in a console window:

> ```
> findstr /s "SaveToDXF_DuplicateCreateCount" *.config
> ```

I performned the test on my C drive and it came up with three files and one of them seemed to be the file of interest:

> ```
> c:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Bricsys\DefaultDomain_Path_LOTSOFCHARACTERS\21.2.06.0\user.config
> ```

The `LOTSOFCHARACTERS` was a weird sequence of text. But when I open that `user.config` file it had my current settings.

I am not sure as the the reason for my settings being persisted in this manner.

---

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60117461/2287576) prrovided to a differeht question actually explains the aforementioned. To quote:

> User Settings (Settings in the User scope) (applies to Visual Studio
> 2017+) These settings are stored along with the Application settings,
> but have associated local storage files, used to store values that a
> User (or the Application) can change at run-time:
>
> 2.1 A user.config file stored in the current User profile in the
>
> ```
> [User]/AppData/Local/[CompanyName]/[ProductName].exe_<hash>/[Assembly Version]
> ```
>
> section, if the setting's Roaming attribute is set to false.
>
> 2.2 A user.config file stored in the current User profile in the
>
> ```
> [User]/AppData/Roaming/[CompanyName]/[ProductName]/[File Version]
> ```
>
> section, if the setting Roaming attribute is set to true instead.