# Where are settings values stored for a Windows forms application?

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, app-config, my.settings

I have a Windows forms application. When I view settings on the Settings tab of my project properties and when I look at App.config, I see one set of values. When I view the values for some of the properties in a message box in the main form's New subroutine, I see different values. I have no idea where these different values are coming from. Any ideas where else to look for property values that would be overriding what's in App.config? Thanks!

Comment: app.config store the default values (which you can reset). The current values (in the `User` scope) are stored in the `user.config` file in the `AppData` folder of the current User (`AppData\Local` or `AppData\Roaming`, depending on how a setting is configured). -- See the notes at the bottom of this Q&A: [How to get the current value of a Property Setting at run-time using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60117461/7444103)

Comment: From explorer, you can get to Roaming as %appdata% and to Local as %localappdata%.

Answer (score 0):

I found this after coming here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/app-settings/how-to-read-application-settings

You can read a user setting by accessing the setting's property on the My.Settings object.

The **My.Settings** object exposes each setting as a property. The property name is the same as the setting name, and the property type is the same as the setting type. The setting's Scope indicates if the property is read-only; the property for an Application scope setting is read-only, while the property for a User scope setting is read-write. For more information, see My.Settings Object.

Example
This example displays the value of the Nickname setting.

```
    Sub ShowNickname()
        MsgBox("Nickname is " & My.Settings.Nickname)
    End Sub
```

For this example to work, your application must have a Nickname setting, of type String. For more information, see Managing Application Settings (.NET).

Answer (score -1):

do you try checking on the `app.config`  `<add name="pointername"` (name) and compare to `properties.settings`? it should be the same with the `app.config`.