# Where are UserSettings.settings stored in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

In Visual Studio I have a Windows Forms Application in C#. I store settings created by the user at runtime in UserSettings.Settings.

When I copy the project folder, and run the application, the settings I saved are gone. That is, all the settings revert to the default. It is as if I had never saved any UserSettings. They are also gone from the original project.

Where are the settings files UserSettings.settings, and Settings.settings?

There are a number of questions posted that come close to answering the questions, but nothing that leads me to them.

Comment: See the notes at the bottom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60117461/7444103) -- These settings are application *version* specific. What *version* means here can be a somewhat *surprising concept*, as you have noticed. See the full documentation on [ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

Please check in Project Folder, check below image

[image]