# Properties.Settings.Default is not working after I publish my Winforms Project

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, stringcollection

I have a TreeView in which I show the Folder Structure of my PC. I built in a Feature, that opens the last selected Path when opening the Application again. To save these Paths, I created a Setting with a System.Collections.Specialised.StringCollection. My Code works fine when I eaither start it via Visual Studio or in my Repository bin Folder. But as soon as I publish the product and start it on my Computer. It's not working. It tells me, that my Properties.Settings.Default.lastSelectedPaths is null.

Any tips?

I haven't found any useful tips online.

Comment: New deployment = new hash = new path = new user.config. See the note here: [How to get the current value of a Property Setting at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60117461/7444103)